# What are the differences in for RTL bidi (Arabic/Hebrew) support in different versions of Android?

Tags: android, arabic, right-to-left, android-version, bidi

I am looking at supporting RTL in Android and trying to figure out how much effort it would take to support multiple Android OS versions. I know that 4.2 started limited bidirectional (bidi) support. And I know before that, bidi support was much more difficult. But how is it more difficult? If you have had experience with this, what are the differences in different versions of Android in regards to RTL/bidi support? What becomes available as the newer version appear?

A key point in a comparison chart of versions is: at what point and version does bidi support take far too much effort that it's not worth it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> at what point and version does bidi support take far too much effort that it's not worth it?

Your mileage may vary. The key is that if an RTL language is available on device, then a resonable support for this language is available too. Samsung, HTC, LG, Motorola and others had such support long before 4.2.

The major improvements that come with standard OS are automatic mirroring support (e.g. `paddng_start` instead of `padding_left`), which theoretically allows to reuse same layout.xml files for LTR and RTL languages. But if support for Arabic is essential to your app, you will probably find it right to prepare separate layouts.

The major problem with earlier versions that have non-google support for RTL is that such support is not predictable. One device may decide to mirror your layout when you switch to RTL language, another will do it only for text widgets, yet another will change arrow direction.

Keyboards may also cause problems. Note that 3rd party keyboards are popular in these countries, and they sometimes try to outsmart the system, with varying results.

The bottom line is that going for any version below 4.2 requires careful testing with real devices that are popular in the target market, you simply cannot open the app in emulator and be satisfied.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of hell. But if it were easy, we would have not been payed premium wages.

Comment: That's true. But I'm just trying to figure out which OS's are worth supporting, devices aside.